When I use ByteStream In rocket , how should I add custom headers?
When I use ByteStream, how should I add custom headers?
I'm trying to implement reverse proxy functionality with Rocket, allowing users to stream downloads by passing a URL parameter. My current code is as follows:
#[rocket::get("/proxy/<_..>")]
async fn handle_proxy(proxyreq: ProxyReq) -> Result<ByteStream![Bytes], (Status, String)> {
    let url = proxyreq.0;
    let host = proxyreq.1;
    if check_domain_is_allowed(&url, &host) {
        let proxy_resp = reqwest::get(&url)
            .await.map_err(|e| (Status::BadRequest, e.to_string()))?;
        let bytes_stream = proxy_resp.bytes_stream();
        Ok(ByteStream! {
            for await bytes in bytes_stream {
                match bytes {
                    Ok(bytes) => yield bytes,
                    Err(e) => {
                        eprintln!("error while streaming: {}", e);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
       Err((Status::BadRequest, "url is not allowed".to_owned()))
    }
}

It appears to be running fine so far. The only issue is that there is no Content-Length field in the response header, so the download progress cannot be displayed on the browser side. I want to retrieve the Content-Length field from the proxy_resp header and add it to the response header. However, I'm not sure how to do that. I tried using Responser, but without success.
